# Check that each Color field has a color value (format string "#FFFFFF")

Tags: java, rest-assured, autotest

I have task: "Check that each Color field has a color value (format string "#FFFFFF")".

I have a solution:

```
@Test
public void sixTest() {
    Specification.installSpec(Specification.requestSpec(), Specification.responseSpec());
    Response response = given()
            .when()
            .get("https://reqres.in/api/unknown")
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract().response();

    ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
    String bodyAsString = body.asString();
    Assert.assertEquals(bodyAsString.contains("#"), true, "Response body contains #");

}
```

I think I solved the problem incorrectly is there a more suitable solution?

Additional information: The URL https://reqres.in/api/unknown is public and returns e.g.

```
{
    page: 1,
    per_page: 6,
    total: 12,
    total_pages: 2,
    data: [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "cerulean",
    year: 2000,
    color: "#98B2D1",
    pantone_value: "15-4020"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "fuchsia rose",
    year: 2001,
    color: "#C74375",
    pantone_value: "17-2031"
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you think you have solved it incorrectly? Is there an error? What are the contents of the response?

Comment: There is no error, I just want to improve the code and make the color check more correct if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using [regular expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java)

```
ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
String bodyAsString = body.asString();

//Regexp for a HEX color
String patternString = "#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

//Check that the text matches the regular expression
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```

You can experiment with regular expressions [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output)

Comment: assertTrue(matches) - why are we writing it? The code throws an exception on it. Everything seems to work correctly without it

Comment: It can be removed.

Comment: I just get an exception on the assert, apparently because the value of the field must contain all the elements patternString

Comment: or rather, why matches returns false

Answer (score 1):

I have same idea with Arthur but more specific what to be tested.

Check every color match the regex `#[0-9A-Z]{6}`

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

Response res = given().get("https://reqres.in/api/unknown");
List<String> colors = res.jsonPath().getList("data.color");
assertThat(colors, everyItem(matchesPattern("#[0-9A-Z]{6}")));
```

Note: Hamcrest verion 1.x doesn't have method `matchesPattern`

Add version 2.2 to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

More info: [api docs](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#matchesPattern-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Where did the 'List<String> colors = res.jsonPath().getList("data.color");' come from?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster from the json in the link `https://reqres.in/api/unknown`

Comment: Tnx, just figured that out now and updated the question.

Comment: I don't understand what "matchesPattern" does

Comment: just i have exception : "Cannot resolve method 'matchesPattern'"

Comment: Did you import `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;`?

Comment: @OttoRahn `matchesPattern` means each item in `colors` list will match regex pattern

Comment: Yes I imported:

 static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
 static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

Comment: Could you try `MatcherAssert.assertThat(colors, Matchers.everyItem(Matchers.matchesPattern("#[0-9A-Z]{6}")));`?

Comment: the same mistake: Cannot resolve method 'matchesPattern' in 'Matchers'

Comment: Make sure you have hamcrest version 2.x in classpath.

Comment: do you mean to add hamcrest dependency to POM?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer.

Comment: does not work, the same mistake "Cannot resolve method 'matchesPattern' in 'Matchers'"

Comment: Maybe it's IDE problem, try to rebuild or Invalide Cache & Restart. If it doesn't work, then you should follow other answers, I cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

In first place read the response with a json parser.
I used Jackson:

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.0
> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0

After travers to `data` array-node and iterate every element and check the `color` node.

```
public static boolean everythingIsColor(String json) throws JsonProcessingException{

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonBody = objectMapper.readTree(json); //JsonProcessingException

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#[0-9A-F]{6}"); //regex for color format

    JsonNode dataNode = jsonBody.get("data");
    for(JsonNode node : dataNode){

        JsonNode colorNode = node.get("color");
        if(!colorNode.isTextual()){ //is not text node
            return false;
        }

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(colorNode.asText());
        if(!matcher.matches()){ //does not match with color format
            return false;
        }

    }

    //if reach here means every color node has a color value
    return true;

}
```